# is the Vuex mutation written correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex, store

I wonder if the mutation method is written correctly and can modify the initial state array ? I'm not sure if the last lines of mutation method are written ok. Am I not missing anything ?

```js
// Store 

state: {
  flights: [
    {trip_class: 0, number_of_change="1"},
    {trip_class: 1, number_of_change="2"},
    {trip_class: 1, number_of_change="1"}...
  ]
}           // expecting to filter the array

mutations: {
  setFilteredFlights: (state, data) => {
      // flight classes
      if (...) {
        state.flights.filter(
          (flight) =>
            flight.trip_class === data.selectedFlightClass ||
            flight.number_of_changes === data.selectedChanges
        );
      }
      //flight changes
      else if (...) {
        state.flights;                             // not sure about this line of code
      }
    },
}
```

Comment: This is the continuation of the previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76252254/why-the-mutation-isnt-filtering-the-store-data-vuex . The answer is no.  state.flights.filter and `state.flights;` are no-op. You need to assign the result to something. This is basic JS problem, not specific to Vuex.

Comment: But with state.flights.filter am I not simply modifying the array ? Why do I need to assign this result to a new array as you might say ?

Comment: And with state.flights; I would need to keep the initial array (not changed), si I wonder how should I do it ?

Comment: No. A few array methods like splice and sort modify an array. Most don't. As said, these are the things that are fundamental to JS, checking them before jumping deep into framework use can save a lot of hours. You don't need `else if (...)` at all if it does nothing. In such cases you usually need another state like filteredFlights independent from flights to not destroy the overall fetched data.

Comment: Thanks. I think a better approach is creating a getter instead of mutaion? How do you think ?

Comment: This will work too. But you need to store `data` in a store then because it's needed in a getter

Comment: Yes, I have this stated array, which later is iterrated with v-for in the component. But how the v-for would look then in the component if I will need after filterring to call the global getters ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it would be `v-for="flight in filteredFlights"`, where filteredFlights is vuex getter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flights` is your main array that holds the flights objects. It would be much easier to just use a getter (or a couple of getters) to get your filtered data, without having to mutate the state.

```
getters: {
  getFlightsByTripClass: (state) => (tripClass) => {
    return state.flights.filter(flight => flight.trip_class === tripClass);
  }
}
```

To use this getter in your Vue component, you can access it using `this.$store.getters`:

```
computed: {
  filteredFlights() {
    return this.$store.getters.getFlightsByTripClass(1);
  }
}
```

Also, for good measure, make sure to follow the camel case convention for your variables. Use `numberOfChange`, instead of `number_of_change`.

Comment: This approach is really fast! But is it possible to use the same getter in computed property if I need to filter by multiple selectors (filters) ? Or should I be using several getters? I mean if the point is to filter the initaial array with several selectors?

Comment: If you want to filter by multiple criteria (e.g. by tripClass and numberOfChange) I would advise you to create a getter that allows a filter by multiple criteria.
If you want to just have different types of filters, I would advise you to create multiple getters.
In any case, it's valuable to keep your filters (getters) in the Vuex store, so you can access them from any component. You will also most likely want to keep your getter reactive in your component, so you should definitely put it in a computed property.